# Simulating black hole / whirpool behaviour for sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, physics, game-physics

One of the powerups in my game is a vortex that attracts all coins. I know I have any cocos2d's moveto/bezierto methods available, but I don't know how to make them have tangential and radial speed.

The extra difficulty is that the vortex center can change in every step, so all movement has to be readjusted.

Comment: I think there is an attractor field in box2d demo. I think you can look at its source code. Quite sure it is possible, since Angry Birds Space uses that feature of box2d.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670991

Comment: Sort of, yes, but I would like a solution without box2d.

Comment: why? box2d is rather good solution

Comment: Definitely a case where you don't want to use actions. Use Box2D, or manually animate the objects. Move and bezier actions (or any actions for that matter) weren't made for frequently changing conditions, such as a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this without a physics engine is to use the [rotation around point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249083/is-this-how-rotation-about-a-point-is-done) algorithm.

That covers the rotation around the vortex center. Once an object is rotation around the vortex, all you need to do is to reduce that object's distance from the center by a certain amount every frame. That way it will continue to move inwards.

The only tricky part then is to get the object from its initial position being "sucked into" the vortex. There's going to be a lot of tweaking needed. With a physics engine, that part would come natural from the physics itself and it would always look right.

This is not guaranteed for the manual solution and definitely not for actions, which aren't designed to track moving targets. For example, if you change a move action every frame by replacing the existing one with a new one, your object won't move at all. Every time you do that, there's a 1-frame delay before the new action does its work.

Comment: I have an "influence box" and a "scape box". If the bounding box of the item collides with the influence box it will be checked for movement every n-th frame so I can make a polygon simulating the spiral. Once the scape box is reached the sprite is deleted.