# Rotate a 2D triangle product odd result

Tags: java

I have a triangle with the points [0, 20], [15, -10], [-15, -10]. Now I want to rotate this triangle by 1 degrees, 2 degrees etc.

Im following the formula provided in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249083/is-this-how-rotation-about-a-point-is-done):

```
x' = cos(theta)*x - sin(theta)*y
y' = sin(theta)*x + cos(theta)*y
```

My java code is:

```
theta = 0;
x1 = 0;
y1 = 20;
x2 = 15;
y2 = -10;
x3 = -15;
y3 = -10;

System.out.println("--------------------adjusted to 0, 0 --------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("[" + x1 + ", "+ y1 + "] " + "[" + x2 + ", " + y2 + "] [" + x3 + ", " + y3 + "]");

x1 = (cos(theta) * x1) - (sin(theta) * y1);
y1 = (sin(theta) * x1) + (cos(theta) * y1);
x2 = (cos(theta) * x2) - (sin(theta) * y2);
y2 = (sin(theta) * x2) + (cos(theta) * y2);
x3 = (cos(theta) * x3) - (sin(theta) * y3);
y3 = (sin(theta) * x3) + (cos(theta) * y3);

System.out.println("-------------------- rotated --------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("[" + x1 + ", "+ y1 + "] " + "[" + x2 + ", " + y2 + "] [" + x3 + ", " + y3 + "]");
```

The output to this produces the inexplicable result:

```
--------------------adjusted to 0, 0 --------------------------------------------
[0.0, 20.0] [15.0, -10.0] [-15.0, -10.0]
-------------------- rotated --------------------------------------------
[-16.829418, -3.355421] [16.519243, 8.49744] [0.31017494, -5.1420197]
```

When I plot this, the triangle looks completely skewed.

Have I completely misinterpreted how to do this?

Comment: working fine for me (with `theta = 0`), had to declare each variables as `double` and use `import static java.lang.Math.*;` *but*... there is another **error**: using the already altered value of `x1` in the formula for `y1` - same for `x2` and `x3`

Comment: **PLEASE** post the correct code, the given results are for `theta = 1` and not `= 0`!!!

Comment: You might consider using respective classes, like a matrix and vector class, together with a rotation function, for readability. Like "for all vectors v in triangle, rotate(v, degree)" and "rotate(v, degree): create rotation matrix rot, return v * rot"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not reuse your variables.

You use `x1` in second line of the transformation, after you changed the value of `x1` in the first line of the transformation.

Look at the formula / function! `x'` is another variable as `x`.

Try using a second set of variable. Better create a class Point containing x and y. Another class Triangle containing three Points. Then create a Triangle `A` and a Triangle `B`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following program to test:

```
double theta = 1;
double x1 = 0;
double y1 = 20;
double x2 = 15;
double y2 = -10;
double x3 = -15;
double y3 = -10;

BufferedImage bim=new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)bim.getGraphics();
Polygon pl=new Polygon();               
pl.addPoint((int)x1, (int)y1); pl.addPoint((int)x2, (int)y2); pl.addPoint((int)x3, (int)y3);                
pl.translate(100, 100);             
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.fill(pl);

double newx1 = (Math.cos(theta) * x1) - (Math.sin(theta) * y1);
double  newy1 = (Math.sin(theta) * x1) + (Math.cos(theta) * y1);
double  newx2 = (Math.cos(theta) * x2) - (Math.sin(theta) * y2);
double  newy2 = (Math.sin(theta) * x2) + (Math.cos(theta) * y2);
double  newx3 = (Math.cos(theta) * x3) - (Math.sin(theta) * y3);
double  newy3 = (Math.sin(theta) * x3) + (Math.cos(theta) * y3);

Polygon pl2=new Polygon();              
pl2.addPoint((int)newx1, (int)newy1); pl2.addPoint((int)newx2, (int)newy2);   pl2.addPoint((int)newx3, (int)newy3);             
pl2.translate(200, 200);                
g.setColor(Color.yellow);
g.fill(pl2);

.... display image bim here
```

Indeed it produces this result

[image]

When I convert the angle to radians however it produces this

```
double theta = Math.toRadians(1);
```

[image]

and when I turn the angle to 10 degrees

```
double theta = Math.toRadians(10);
```

[image]

--

You also need to make sure you use the previous coordinates in both  equations, as updated above.

Finally your polygon needs to be centered, as it seems to be the current one; othwerise you need to find the center which is another question.

Comment: still wrong: using 'rotated' `x1` to calculate `y1`- try it with bigger angles like 60 (~ 1 rad), 70 or even 80 degrees - the error is just not that obvious with smaller angles like 10°

Comment: but nice visualization!